# How can I obtain data flow graph along with c-use and p-use variables of a C code?

Tags: testing, control-flow, dataflow, control-flow-graph, dataflow-diagram

Is there any online tool/software(open-source preferred) that makes data flow graph of a C code and also gives p-use and c-use variables in it.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but did you manage to find one?

Answer (score 0):

Given a tool that provides def-use chains (and vice versa) you can compute c-use and p-use pretty easily.

I know of 3 tools that can do this for C:

- GCC
- Clang
- DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit

(What do you mean "online"?)